# Sqlmock + Gorm fails with Error "unsupported data type: &[]"

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I try to test gorm things with sqlmock.

My model looks like:

```golang
type Worker struct {
  Model
  NetworkAddress string
  Name           string
  Version        string
  Available      bool
  Services       []Service `gorm:"foreignKey:WorkerId;references:Id"`
}
```

I got following Error:

```
unsupported data type: &[]: Table not set, please set it like: db.Model(&user) or db.Table("users")
```

the test:

```golang
db, mock := createMock(t)
repo = db
row := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "network_address", "version", "name"}).AddRow("1", "test", "1.0", "test")
mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta("SELECT * FROM `workers` WHERE `workers`.`id` = ? AND `workers`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `workers`.`id` LIMIT 1")).
    WithArgs(1).
    WillReturnRows(row)
db.Con.Table("Services")
worker, err := FindWorkerByConds(1)
if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("expected query to be executred, got error %s", err)
}
if worker.Name != "test" {
    t.Error("expected name to be test")
}
```

the function:

```golang
var (
    worker  *models.Worker
    tx      *gorm.DB
)
worker = &models.Worker{}
// use builder to load preload conditions
tx = repo.Build().Preload("Services").First(worker, conds)
return worker, tx.Error
```

Build is just a helper which returns `*gorm.DB`

Running the example works like expected but trying to unit test this fails.